# XML Comparison details with XDiff and .NEt

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I just would like to ask if there is a way that I could get the XML difference details for 2 compared files in XDiff and Patch in .NET?

When doing comparisons in XDiff and Patch, it only brings back a bool value whether 2 xml documents are the same or not.

Thanks!

Ann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you referring to `Microsoft.XmlDiffPath.XmlDiff`?  If so, it has an overload for Compare that provides an XmlWriter to write the differences to.

```
XmlDiff comparer = new XmlDiff();
bool differences = comparer.compare(xmlNode1, xmlNode2, xmlWriter);
```

Comment: Yes. I'll try this out and see how it goes. Thanks again! :)